# How to call my fragments from a General method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a general method to call all my fragments from one place

I have tried to make a method called open fragment and pass all the needed parameters such bundle and the next fragment as Object class

and pass any another needed parametres.

```
public static void openFragment(Bundle bundle, Fragment nextFrag, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {

    nextFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager manager = (appCompatActivity)
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_body, nextFrag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

R.id.container_body  // this may be changed

Comment: what error you see

Comment: 1.) there is no guarantee that `Object` is a fragment, 2.) there is no guarantee that `Context` is an `AppCompatActivity`, and 3.) there is no guarantee that the `Bundle` is filled with the arguments that the Fragment requires to function. Why are you trying to write/use this method? It is unsafe. Just not having this function would already be a clearer solution.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your method like this:

```
public static void openFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, Fragment nextFrag, View containerView) {
        FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(containerView.getId(), nextFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
  }
```

Now you can add the Fragment to the FragmentTransaction, considering `FirstFragment` is your `Fragment` class :

```
FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("extraData", data);
firstFragment.setArguments(bundle);
containerView = findViewById(R.id.container_body);
openFragment(yourActivity.this, firstFragment , containerView);
```

Here, the point is your `container_body` view should be accessible from your calling class (Activity/Fragment). i.e. `container_body` should be a child of the parent layout from where the call is being made.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure R.id.container_body must be an id of [frameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout).

You can make a new method inside the Fragment class to get the new instance of fragment wherever its required.

```
public class FragmentExample extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentExample newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FragmentExample fragment = new FragmentExample();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

you can call `openFragment(FragmentExample.newInstance())`

```
public void openFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.flcontent, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```